Describe the relation between the homology groups of space $ X $ and suspension $ S(X) $.
This question is from a publicly available practice qualifying exam (Stanford geometry and topology), which I am using to help learn this field. The only recommended book for this question is Hatcher's Algebraic Topology.

Question: Let $ X $ be a topological space. Define the suspension $ S(X) $ to be the space obtained from $ X \times [0,1] $ by contracting $ X \times \{0\} $ to a point, and contracting $ X \times \{1\} $ to another point. Describe the relation between the homology groups of $ X $ and $ S(X) $.

Answer:
First, notation: $C_X$ is the cone of space $X$, and have $S(X) := S_X$. Infix $\leftrightarrow$ denotes an isomorphism. All other notation is highly standard and can be found in any textbook on the subject.
For a good pair $(Y, A)$, we have a segment of the long exact (LE) sequence for some $n$:
$$ H_n (A) \rightarrow H_n(Y) \rightarrow H_n(Y, A) \rightarrow H_{n-1} (A) \rightarrow H_{n-1}(Y) $$
First choose $Y = S_X$ and $A = C_X$. Then our segment contains a short exact sequence:
$$ 0 \rightarrow H_n(S_X) \rightarrow H_n(S_X, C_X) \rightarrow 0 \rightarrow 0$$
from which we can discern that $\boxed{ H_n(S_X) \leftrightarrow H_n(S_X, C_X) }$.
Next choose $Y = C_X$ and $A = X$. Then our segment contains a short exact sequence:
$$ H_n (X) \rightarrow 0 \rightarrow H_n(C_X, X) \rightarrow H_{n-1} (X) \rightarrow 0$$
from which we can discern that $\boxed{H_n(C_X, X) \leftrightarrow H_{n-1} (X)}$.
Now, consider that two pairs are homotopically equivalent if the matching first entries are homotopically equivalent and the matching second entries are homotopically equivalent.   Note also that if two good pairs are homotopically equivalent then their relative homology groups are isomorphic.
Have $p$ be one of the polar points (the quotient of $X \times \{1 \}$ or $X \times \{ 0\}$). We could also have $p$ be a small neighborhood around one of these polar points depending on the topology.
From the excision theorem:
$$ H_n (S_X \, , \, C_X) \leftrightarrow H_n(S_X - p  ,  C_X - p )  \leftrightarrow H_n (C_X, X)$$
then we have a chain of isomorphisms
$$ H_n(S_X) \leftrightarrow H_n(S_X, C_X) \leftrightarrow H_n (C_X, X) \leftrightarrow H_{n-1} (X)$$
to avoid pathological cases (such as spheres) treat our LE sequence of relative groups as being the LE sequence of reduced homology groups. The isomorphisms we obtained above still hold, which gives
$$ \tilde H_n(S_X) \leftrightarrow \tilde H_n(S_X / C_X) \leftrightarrow \tilde H_n (C_X / X) \leftrightarrow \tilde H_{n-1} (X)$$
then we have for all $n \ge 1$ that:
$$\boxed{ \tilde H_n(S_X) \leftrightarrow \tilde H_{n-1} (X) }$$

Is my final solution (last boxed part) correct?
I found the relation between isomorphisms, the relative homology groups, and the reduced homology groups to be the slipperiest part.
How would I best manage the interplay between those two. It's easy in my proof for me to slip up and state that $  H_n(S_X) \leftrightarrow \tilde H_{n-1} (X) $ for all $n$, which spheres of higher dimension easily prove as being false. I added in a part about turning the relative LE sequence into a reduced LE sequence and this being isomorphism preserving but it still felt... clunky. Let me know what you think.

Why was Ben’s answer downvoted twice and deleted? Seems to me it addressed your question. I’d say this is not focused enough. Your conclusion is correct, concretely, what else do you want? I guess I should only say the same things Ben said. You don’t need a good pair for any of the LES you used unless you want to replace with quotients (which you don’t have to) and you may as well have begun with reduced homology as it conveniently erases path connected spaces in degree zero, and erases acyclic spaces such as a cone.
